# preg_match not giving expected output

Tags: php, regex, pcre

I have the following code which is to extract the last to segments from a domain name:

example: `xkcd.com` should be extracted from `http://www.xckd.com`

```
<?php
    if( isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'])) {   

        $from = "host origin";

        $origin_in = $_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'];

        preg_match('/[^.]+\.[^.]+$/', $origin_in, $matches);
        $origin_out = $matches[0];


        print_r($matches);

    } else if($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']) {

        $from = "server name";

        $origin_in = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];

        preg_match('/[^.]+\.[^.]+$/', $origin_in, $matches);
        $origin_out = $matches[0];
    }

    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *" );
    echo "origin input: ". $origin_in. "\n";
    echo "origin output: ". $origin_out. "\n";
    echo "from: ". $from;
    exit();
```

I have posted my code verbatim to be the most accurate representation of what is being processed as i am uncertain of where things are going wrong.

The output I get is

```
Array
(
    [0] => http://xxxx.com
)
origin input: http://xxxx.com
origin output: http://xxxx.com
from: host origin
```

Why am I not getting `xxxx.com` for the origin output?

My code can be contrasted against this snippet which works as expected: http://3v4l.org/nNKZn

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Check out http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php

Comment: The difference in the snippet is that the URL has 2 dots, your URL only has 1.

Comment: @mkaatman Thank you. This will be helpful in solving the problem, and I will use it in the meantime. However I am still interested as to why I am not getting the expected output if anyone is able to shed light on it.

Comment: It's precisely because of the two dots. The RE matches a string with no dot, followed by a dot, then a string with no dot, followed by the end of the string. In the snippet, the part that matches this is after the first dot. In your code, the entire URL matches it.

Comment: @Barmar you were correct after all. Thanks.